# plot the line of the average y for each x in r

Tags: r, plot

for example, let's use the ozone data from `airquality` I have discrete x values (Wind) and y values (Ozone). some of the y values in ozone share the same x values so I want to take the average of there y values and plot that. 
e.g

(5, 10)

(5, 20)

(5, 40)

we would plot (5, 23.33). I would do this for all the x values and connect them all.

I tried this, but I don't see the line for some reason..

```
data(airquality)
plot(Ozone ~ Wind, data = airquality)
lines(weighted.mean(airquality$Ozone, airquality$Wind))
```

Comment: Could you base your example on `data(airquality)` instead, so we don't have to install a new package just for this question?

Comment: Is the x values discrete or continuous? What you are doing only makes sense if discrete. For continuous just try fitting a regression line else your lines will be all over the place. For discrete you can calculate the average for each x value before plotting `df <- ozone %>% group_by(wind) %>% summarize(wind = mean(wind))`

Comment: yea i should have mentioned that wind is discrete

Comment: @AkselA it is airquality now

Comment: `Wind` is not discrete in the `airquality` data. But that does not necessarily matter for grouping and summary.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? If either did, you should accept it, if none did, you need to explain what they got wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for.

As `Wind` is continuous, if we want to group by it we'll have to discretize it somehow. I chose to do it by grouping `Wind` by quantile, or more specifically, decile. Then I computed the mean of `Ozone`, grouped by those `Wind` quantiles.

```
data(airquality)

br <- quantile(airquality$Wind, seq(0, 1, length=11))

mid <- br[-length(br)] + diff(br)/2

wind.bin <- cut(airquality$Wind, breaks=br)

agg.oz <- aggregate(airquality$Ozone, list(wind.bin), mean, na.rm=TRUE)

colnames(agg.oz) <- c("Wind.mean", "Ozone.mean")
agg.oz[1] <- mid

plot(Ozone ~ Wind, data=airquality, pch=16, cex=0.6)
abline(v=br, col="#00000022", lty=2)
lines(agg.oz, col="red", type="o", pch=16)
legend("topright", legend="Mean ozone by \nwind quantile", 
  col="red", lwd=1.1, bty="n", cex=0.8)
```

[image]

If you insist on treating `Wind` as discrete values you can do it like this

```
data(airquality)

airquality <- airquality[complete.cases(airquality),]

agg.oz <- aggregate(Ozone ~ Wind, data=airquality, mean, na.rm=TRUE)

colnames(agg.oz) <- c("Wind.mean", "Ozone.mean")

plot(Ozone ~ Wind, data=airquality, pch=16, cex=0.6)
lines(agg.oz, col="red", type="o", pch=16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you are using `weighted.mean`. However, you can see why there's no line:

```
weighted.mean(airquality$Ozone, airquality$Wind)
[1] NA
```

Adding the `na.rm = TRUE` argument will still return just one value:

```
weighted.mean(airquality$Ozone, airquality$Wind, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 34.99825
```

Perhaps we will stick with `mean` for now, until we understand the data better.

Plotting a summary by mean is pretty straightforward in `ggplot2` using `stat_summary`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(airquality, aes(Wind, Ozone)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = mean)
```

I'd suggest a couple of enhancements:

- Showing the original data points so we know how many observations went into the mean
- adding a smoothed line

  ```
  ggplot(airquality, aes(Wind, Ozone)) + 
    geom_point(color = "grey90") + 
    stat_summary(geom = "point", 
                 fun.y = mean, 
                 color = "red") + 
    geom_smooth()
  ```

Result:

[image]